# Extracting names from PDFs containing emails

Tags: r, regex, pdf

I have a very specific question. I have a set of PDF files that contain emails (and email chains) and are generally of the following format:

```
From: Doe, John <john.doe@mail.com>
To: Doe, Jane <john.doe@mail.com>; Doe, John
Subject: Re: Title
text ...
...
From: Doe, John <john.doe@mail.com>
To: Doe, Jane <john.doe@mail.com>; Doe, John
CC: Moe, James; Klein, John
Subject: Title
text ...
```

So, in one PDF file, you generally have several "from", "to" and "cc" blocks. The format of the names is always that last name and first name are seperated by a comma. Different names are separated by a semi colon. However, sometimes the full email address (which I do not need) will be included between "<" and ">". I would like to extract all of the names (in the from, to, and cc parts) from these PDF files and in the end have output that looks like this:

```
Last name    first name
Doe          John
Doe          Jane
Moe          James
Klein        John
```

I have managed to read in the PDF files using the `pdftools` package:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
pdfs <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
```

However, I am currently a bit stuck in trying to find the best way to extract all of the names and save them in a data frame. I have been looking at the `str_extract` function: e.g. starting with `str_extract(pdfs[[1]], regex("From.*To", ignore_case = TRUE))`, but haven't been able to find a working solution. Any help would be much appreciated. As an example, assume that `pdfs[[1]]` contains the following string:

```
teststring <- "From: Doe, John <john.doe@mail.com>\r\n
To: Doe, Jane <john.doe@mail.com>; Doe, John\r\n
Subject: Re: Title\r\n
text ...\r\n
...\r\n
From: Doe, John <john.doe@mail.com>\r\n
To: Doe, Jane <john.doe@mail.com>; Doe, John\r\n
CC: Moe, James; Klein, John\r\n
Subject: Title\r\n
text ...\r\n"
```

Comment: What "unreliable" ways did you try that didn't work? Unless, you're just looking for free consulting .

Comment: I was merely trying to get advice from more knowledgeable users as I thought was appropriate here. I have tried many different approaches like piecing everything together with the `str_extract` function.  E.g. starting with `str_extract(pdfs[[1]], regex("From.*To", ignore_case = TRUE))`. However, I have not found a working solution yet, especially when trying to extract last and first names appropriately. I am not asking for a full solution, but possible pointers to useful packages or functions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make the question more specific? I also do not see how unreliable your ways are given you know the format of the emails.

Comment: I have made edits to the question to reflect that I am unsure how to best approach extracting the names. I have tried using the `str_extract` function, but have not found a working solution. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `teststring`

```
library(stringr)
fullnames <- unique(c(str_extract_all(teststring, "[a-zA-Z]+,\\s[a-zA-Z]+", simplify=TRUE)))
splitnames <- unlist(strsplit(fullnames, ","))
ans <- data.frame(Last=splitnames[c(TRUE,FALSE)], First=splitnames[c(FALSE,TRUE)])
```

Output

```
   Last  First
1   Doe   John
2   Doe   Jane
3   Moe  James
4 Klein   John
```

Comment: This works great.  I have used a way more complicated version using `regmatches` and `gsub`, but this is much more elegant. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help